# Done key in iPhone app that closes keyboard (with UITextView)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard-layout

I'm working on an iPhone app and in the iPhone app the user is typing in an UITextView.
I was wondering how I could add the done key on the keyboard instead of having the normal return key and when you click on that key the keyboard closes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is no `-textViewShouldReturn:` method in the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol. If you want the return (done) key to dismiss the keyboard, it's probably best to use a UITextField instead, `UITextView` is intended for editing multiple lines of text (so you need a way to enter a linebreak).

If you really want to dismiss the keyboard when hitting the return key in a `UITextView`, you could probably do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
  if ([text isEqual:@"\n"]) {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The reason I was in need of using a TextView is because the app I'm working on is a Twitter API. And if the user would like to read thru the tweet before posting it then that would be a little messier for the user.

Answer (score -4):

It's as simple as:

```
textField.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
```

Add this to your text field's delegate to remove the keyboard when it's pressed:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)aTextfield {
    [aTextfield resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't close the keyboard.

Comment: Sorry about that. Added it to my answer.

Comment: I think the question was referring to UITextView not UITextField

Comment: This isn't answering the question. The question is about UITextView which does not have the delegate method textFieldShouldReturn.

Comment: questioner expected the answer about UITextView

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me as my textFieldShouldEndEditing and textFieldDidEndEditing delegate functions were not being called.

Answer (score -6):

In addition to setting:

```
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

you need to set the text field's delegate to your class, and do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

This setting the returnKeyType can be done from Interface Builder as well - if you have your UI defined in a XIB. On the other hand the -resignFirstResponder will make sure that the keyboard disappears. It should be done in the -textFieldShouldReturn: delegate method, since that is invoked when the user taps on the Done button.

Hope this helps.

Comment: He asks for UITextView not UITextField.

Comment: Also not answering the question.. the question is about UITextView.